# Instance Synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I wrote a small block of code to understand the concepts of `synchronized` blocks:

```
public class ObjectLevelSynchronized {

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Finished.");
            }catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final ObjectLevelSynchronized c = new ObjectLevelSynchronized();
        final ObjectLevelSynchronized c1 = new ObjectLevelSynchronized();       

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                c.run();
                c.run();
            }
        }, "MyThread1");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                c1.run();
                c1.run();
            }
        }, "MyThread2");

        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Only one thread can execute inside a Java code block synchronized on the same monitor object, I am calling `run` method from two different threads and two different instances.

**Expected Result:**

```
MyThread1
MyThread2
MyThread1 Finished
MyThread2 Finished
MyThread1
MyThread2 
MyThread1 Finished
MyThread2 Finished
```

**Actual Result**

```
MyThread1
MyThread1 Finished.
MyThread1
MyThread1 Finished.
MyThread2
MyThread2 Finished.
MyThread2
MyThread2 Finished.
```

Why `synchronized` block, locked the code for two different objects?

Comment: you meant ObjectLevelSynchronized instead of ClassLevelSynchronized in the main method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two different lock.

you use `synchronized(this)`

and you create two objects

```
final ClassLevelSynchronized c = new ClassLevelSynchronized();
final ClassLevelSynchronized c1 = new ClassLevelSynchronized();
```

so, c and c1 is your locks and synchronized looks these locks. you have to use same object for it to synchronize a block. the simplest way for you is

```
private static Object lock = new Object();
```

and use it in synchronized

```
synchronized(lock)
```

or, for your output, this should work too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final ObjectLevelSynchronized c = new ObjectLevelSynchronized();
        final ObjectLevelSynchronized c1 = new ObjectLevelSynchronized();       
        final Object lock = new Object();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    c.run();
                    c.run();
                }
            }
        }, "MyThread1");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    c1.run();
                    c1.run();
                }
            }
        }, "MyThread2");

        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }
```

Comment: I think he wants to have two lock and not one, but getting the behavior like using one lock and asking why it does not act like having two locks.

Comment: but he asked "Why synchronized block, locked the code for two different objects?". actually, as output, it is not needed already any sync block. just calling run functions in order would be enough

Answer (score 0):

My Result is the following like you expected:

```
MyThread2
MyThread1
MyThread2 Finished.
MyThread2
MyThread1 Finished.
MyThread1
MyThread2 Finished.
MyThread1 Finished.
```

When testing multi-threaded programms always try multiple runs because the output is not always the same, because the order of execution may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the type is `ObjectLevelSynchronized`, based on the code you shared, it is not mandatory the program would output the result like the way you shared, as there is `no mechanism` for communication between the two instances of objects you have created and run in different threads. Secondly, The order of Sysout statements is purely based on the discretion of JVM/OS i.e., either of T1 & T2 can run first. So in order to print the out the way you have expected, you have to communicate with other instances on who should print first or in simple words you require a lock to be shared between these two objects that are being run in the threads